# Tizen Emulator - no installable platforms

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator

I have installed the Visual Studio Code extension for Tizen, and (seemingly) that went well.

However, when I fire up the Tizen emulator manager, I have no platforms installed, and when I try to install a platform, there are none available:

[image: Screenshot from Tizen Emulator Manager]

Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

I'm running Windows 10 Pro v 1803 on an Intel i7-8700 CPU @ 3.2 Ghz with 32 GB RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the specific platform you want to work on from the package manager first. Then it's emulator should be available.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding - which package manager is this, specifically?

Comment: the pm is build into tizen or vs for tizen. you have to dl the image first. kind of like android AVM/SDK. i updated my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Emulator images first. You can do this from the Tizen Package Manager.

There is a [helpful guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/visual-studio-code-extension-tizen/installing-visual-studio-code-extension-tizen#install-emulators) on the Tizen developer site that explains you how to do it if you're using VS Code.

> To use the Tizen Package Manager:
>   1. Open the **Command Palette** and enter **tizen package**.
>   2. Select **Tizen .NET: Launch Tizen Package Manager**.
>   3. Select the profiles and versions that you want to install and click  **Install**.

Once you have emulator image(s) installed, you'll be able to select them in the Tizen Emulator Manager.